# Display tooltip on hover in cutom toggle switch

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a custom toggle switch created

When I mousehover on it if the switch is `ON` its  should display the message on tooltip as `YES` and if  `OFF` tooltip meassage should be `NO`.

How can I acheive this in custom toggle switch?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 0;
}
.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* transitions */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
.switch-flat {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px #eceeef;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label:after {
  color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle {
  top: 4px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #dadada;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle:before {
  background: #eceeef;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 55px;
  background: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<label class='switch switch-flat'>
    <input class='switch-input both' type='checkbox' checked />
    <span class='switch-label' data-on='ON' data-off='OFF'></span>
    <span class='switch-handle'></span> 
</label>
```

Comment: Are you want like this [tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)?

Comment: @RayeesAC Yes the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all  added a `<span>` as class name as **tooltiptext** in html inside the **switch label**

```
 <span class="tooltiptext">ON</span>
```

While toggling the **swicth** the text of **tooltiptext** span also changed by

```
$(".switch-input").change(function(){
  if($(".switch-input").prop("checked")){
    $(".tooltiptext").text("ON")
  }else{
    $(".tooltiptext").text("OFF");
  }
});
```

The visiblity of **tooltiptext** become hidden while hover the switch become visible

```
.switch .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.switch:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$(".switch-input").change(function(){
  if($(".switch-input").prop("checked")){
    $(".tooltiptext").text("ON")
  }else{
    $(".tooltiptext").text("OFF");
  }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  margin:50px 45%;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 0;
  
}
.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* transitions */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
.switch-flat {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px #eceeef;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label:after {
  color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle {
  top: 4px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #dadada;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle:before {
  background: #eceeef;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 55px;
  background: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}

/* tooltip */

.switch .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 37px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.switch .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.switch:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='switch switch-flat'>
    <input class='switch-input both' type='checkbox' checked />
    <span class='switch-label' data-on='ON' data-off='OFF'></span>
    <span class='switch-handle'></span> 
    <span class="tooltiptext">ON</span>
</label>
```

Comment: @kavya I added answer. I Hope  you want like this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use script like this:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 0;
}
.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* transitions */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
.switch-flat {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px #eceeef;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-label:after {
  color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle {
  top: 4px;
  left: 5px;
  background: #dadada;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.switch-flat .switch-handle:before {
  background: #eceeef;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-flat .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 55px;
  background: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tooltip {


}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script>
    function content_of_toolTip() {
   
        if (document.getElementById("check").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("tooltipLabel").innerHTML = "yes"
        }
        
        if (document.getElementById("check").checked == false) {
            document.getElementById("tooltipLabel").innerHTML = "no"
        }
        
    }
</script>
<body style="text-align:center;">


 <label class='switch switch-flat tooltip'>
        <input class='switch-input both' id="check" onchange=content_of_toolTip() type='checkbox' checked  />
        <span class='switch-label' data-on='ON' data-off='OFF' onmouseover="content_of_toolTip()" onfocus="content_of_toolTip(this)" ></span>
        <span class='switch-handle'></span>
        <span class="tooltiptext" id="tooltipLabel">Tooltip text</span>
    </label>


</body>
</html>
```